# Java: comparing strings with "-"(dash)

Tags: java, string, compare

I am beginner in Java and probably I am asking something obvious but anyway.

According to Java.Lang.String compareTo() method description:

> The comparison is based on the Unicode value of each character in the strings.

I am comparing strings

```
    public void compareString() {
    String str1 = "test-2014";
    String str2 = "test195519-9022c72bc161";
    String str3 = "test200101-ee4d99b1492c";
    String str4 = "test212941-884e3f03fe1e";

    System.out.println(str1.compareTo(str2));
    System.out.println(str1.compareTo(str3));
    System.out.println(str1.compareTo(str4));
}
------------ OUTPUT -----------
-4
-5
-5
```

I am expecting the output will be the same in all three cases because Unicode value of fifth char in every case (1, 2, 2) is greater than fifth char in "str1" (-).

Could you please explain why it happens?

Thinks

Comment: Go look at an ASCII table, and look how many places seperate the dash from the other characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expect the following

> I am expecting the output will be the same in all three cases because
>   Unicode value of fifth char in every case (1, 2, 2) is greater than
>   fifth char in "str1" (-).

This expectation is wrong. The unicode value of `-` is smaller than the others.

Run this test

```
System.out.println((int) '-');
System.out.println((int) '1');
System.out.println((int) '2');
```

It will print

```
45
49
50
```

45 is smaller than 49, so the method will return a negative value. [As the javadoc says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29)

> the value 0 if the argument string is equal to this string; **a value
>   less than 0 if this string is lexicographically less than the string
>   argument;** and a value greater than 0 if this string is
>   lexicographically greater than the string argument.

For reference, the implementation of `String#compareTo(String)` in Java Oracle 7

```
public int compareTo(String anotherString) {
    int len1 = value.length;
    int len2 = anotherString.value.length;
    int lim = Math.min(len1, len2);
    char v1[] = value;
    char v2[] = anotherString.value;

    int k = 0;
    while (k < lim) {
        char c1 = v1[k];
        char c2 = v2[k];
        if (c1 != c2) {
            return c1 - c2; // important!!!!
        }
        k++;
    }
    return len1 - len2;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't matter which negative number is returned.  The only important piece of information here is the sign of what `compareTo` returns.  It wouldn't matter if it returned `-1`, `-4`, `-5`, or `-1000000`.  The only thing to conclude is that `str1` is less than each of the other strings.

From [the Javadocs for the `compareTo` method in `Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29):

> Compares this object with the specified object for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

Comment: It should be noted that some implementations might incidentally return a useful value that expresses the difference (viz. another answer to this question), but this is not part of the spec and not really to be relied upon.

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere does it say that `compareTo()` should return the index of the first character that doesn't match. This is an incorrect assumption on your part. The only guaranteed result is that its return value will be either negative, positive or zero, depending on the lexicographical comparison of the two strings.

Within each of those 3 possibilities, the actual number that gets returned (-5 vs. -1 vs. -3495582) depends on the implementation (the implementation is free to return whatever it wants, as long as it's negative) and you should make no further assumptions about it.

Comment: I don't think OP actually made that assumption.